# SQL - Really make this Order by?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Code:

```
SELECT FROM PRICE ORDER BY p.name
```

for example we search `test`. in this result will be:

SELECT FROM PRICE WHERE p.name LIKE '%test%' ORDER BY p.name

But i would like change ORDER by on first symbol search word(in my example first symbol word `test` will be `t`).

For example table have rows:

```
p.name

about test
bold test
search test
test test
result test
other test
```

I would like change my example query that result have rows:

```
p.name

test test //first becouse in my example first symbol word `test` will be `t`
about test
bold test
search test
result test
other test
```

Or it not really result should have:

```
p.name

test test //first becouse in my example first symbol word `test` will be `t`
```

Tell me plese it really? and how make it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way:

```
SELECT * FROM PRICE 
WHERE p.name LIKE '%test%' 
ORDER BY 
case
  when p.name like 't%' then 0
  else 1
end, p.name
```

Comment: tell me please how will be order by for row `ORDER BY f.priority, d.end_date, p.name DESC` ?

Comment: I think it should be like this: `order by case ... end, f.priority, d.end_date, p.name DESC`